# Subtract list of boolean

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have two lists of booleans `buy_machine` and `broken_machine`. I want to make a third list `working_machines` that sums the number of machines bought and subtracts the number of broken machines.

I tried the following code and the resulting list is full of `'nothing'` I expected at least to see the `'plus 1'` or `'minus 1'`, this was just to try something, I have no idea how to actually make the `working_machines` list to sum or subtract the booleans

```
years = list(range(1, 21))
buy_machine = []
broken_machine = []
working_machines = []
for year in years:
    if year <= 5:
        buy_machine.append(True)
    else:
        buy_machine.append(False)
    if 10 % year == 10 and year <= 15:
        broken_machine.append(True)
    else:
        broken_machine.append(False)
    if buy_machine == True and broken_machine == False:
        working_machines.append('plus 1')
    elif buy_machine == False and broken_machine == True:
        working_machines.append('minus 1')
    else:
        working_machines.append('nothing')
```

```
buy_machine
[True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]
```

```
broken_machine
[False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]
```

```
working_machines
['nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing',
 'nothing']
```

Wanted output

```
working_machines
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

`working_machines` is just the cumulative sums of the values in the following list:

```
>>> x = [a - b for a,b in zip(buy_machine, broken_machine)]
>>> x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

(This works because `True` and `False` are equal to `1` and `0`, respectively, `bool` being a subclass of `int`.)

You can get that using `itertools.accumulate`.

```
>>> list(accumulate(x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

That is, `working_sums[i] = sum(x[:i])` for each index `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a whole bunch of nothing is that you're asking if the entire list is true, i.e. `buy_machine == True`. Unfortunately, a list cannot equal a boolean, so this is why you always go to the else statement. Try this instead:

```
years = list(range(1, 21))
buy_machine = []
broken_machine = []
working_machines = []
for year in years:
    if year <= 5:
        buy_machine.append(True)
    else:
        buy_machine.append(False)
    if 10 % year == 10 and year <= 15:
        broken_machine.append(True)
    else:
        broken_machine.append(False)
    if buy_machine[-1] == True and broken_machine[-1] == False:
        working_machines.append('plus 1')
    elif buy_machine[-1] == False and broken_machine[-1] == True:
        working_machines.append('minus 1')
    else:
        working_machines.append('nothing')
        
print(working_machines)
# Prints ['plus 1', 'plus 1', 'plus 1', 'plus 1', 'plus 1', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'minus 1', 'minus 1', 'minus 1', 'minus 1', 'minus 1', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing']
```

This uses `buy_machine[-1]` to get the last element of the list, i.e. the element you just added.

Edit: You can change `'plus 1'` to `1` and `'minus 1'` to `-1`, then use the `itertools.accumulate` function as described in Chepner's answer to get what you want.

Comment: I thought that just with the loop `for year in years:` it would take each element, thanks for the tip on using `[-1]`on the list, worked perfectly.